# Complete the sequence if a specific pattern is followed

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

1, 4, 9, 18, 35, _

Find the next number if the occurence of numbers follows a specific order

Comment: This is too broad, I searched [this on OEIS](//oeis.org/search?q=1%2C+4%2C+9%2C+18%2C+35&language=english&go=Search) and got 6 results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 68

Explanation:

> 1*2+2
>
>  4*2+1
>
>  9*2+0
>
>  18*2-1
>
>  35*2-2

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, nice answer.